# How to get a list of users who liked post using Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Post` Model that has a Polymorphic Relation to a `Likes` model by way of this function:

```
public function likes() {
  return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Like', 'likeable');
}
```

Back in my `Likes` model:

```
public function likeable() {
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**UPDATE**

the `likes()` method returns a collection like so:

```
  [  
   {  
      "id":125,
      "user_id":30,
      "likeable_id":1,
      "likeable_type":"App\Models\Post",
      "created_at":"2017-10-13 22:06:13",
      "updated_at":"2017-10-13 22:06:13"
   },
   {  
      "id":126,
      "user_id":17,
      "likeable_id":1,
      "likeable_type":"App\Models\Post",
      "created_at":"2017-10-13 22:06:13",
      "updated_at":"2017-10-13 22:06:13"
   }
  ]
```

Now i want to create another function in my `Post` model that gets each `User` associated with the `user_id` of each `like` object in the returned collection, i've written this so far:

```
public function likeUsers($post) {
  $likes = $post->Likes();
  foreach ($likes as $like) {
    $user = User::find($like->user_id);
    $name = $user->first_name;
    // Here is where i want to push the $name var into a new collection  

  }
   //return new Collection;
}
```

How do I push the each `$name` var in my `foreach` into a new Eloquent collection and return that?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call **getLikes()** directly on your model. Instead, you should access **getLikes** attribute:

```
foreach ($post->getLikes as $like) {
  //$like will contain a model that likes the post
}
```

I also suggest you change the method name from **getLikes()** to **likes()**. It's not a getter but a relation definition and the convention is to name such a method the way you'd name a relation. Then you should be able to access models that like your post with **$post->likes**.

BTW, are you going to have any other model like your posts except Users? If not, you don't need a polymorphic relation for that, **belongsToMany** should be enough.

Comment: As I said, you should never call the likes() method directly. Instead you should read the `likes` attribute, e.g. $likes = $post->likes;. Try that and let me know what you get then.

Comment: ok that gives me the same collection as calling the method directly does... how does that aid me in finding a solution to my updated question?

Comment: Can only users like your posts? Or do you have any other models that can like posts?